# Is there a typo corrector for bash?

Tags: unix, bash, spell-check, typing

I'd like for something to hook into the 'command not found' error on bash and offer a useful fix.

For example:

```
grep-C3  error
bash: grep-C3: command not found
```

It would be nice if it said:

```
Did you mean: grep -C3 error (Y/n)
```

I've seen people include common typos in the .bash_profile script like 'alias gerp=grep', but I figure someone has probably written a general extension to bash to fix this sort of thing.

Has anyone heard of such an extension?

Comment: http://www.catb.org/~esr/jargon/html/D/DWIM.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of a general purpose one, but there is one for directory names:

```
$ shopt -s cdspell
$ cd /usr/ibn
/usr/bin
$ pwd
/usr/bin
$ cd /usr/shar/doc
/usr/share/doc
```

This is from the man page for Bash:

```
If the search is unsuccessful, the shell searches for a defined shell 
function named command_not_found_handle.  If that function exists, it is 
invoked with the original command and the original command's arguments  
as its arguments
```

It might be possible to use this to do what you want, but the code would be quite a challenge. By the way, Ubuntu, for example, uses this to display packages that contain the command that was not found with installation instructions (apt-get).

Answer (score 3):

Looks like [shopt](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) would be a good start.

Also, it appears that [zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/) has typo correction built in.

Comment: link to "shopt" looks like a blank page from here.

Answer (score 0):

the `command-not-found` package should provide this feature in recent distros.

If not, you can invoke it manually from the `command_not_found_handle()` function.

Another alternative is [this](https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck).

Answer (score 0):

There's another tool (with a rude name that can be aliased to `fixthis`), here's what it does for the posted example:

```
kai@PC:~$ grep-C3 error
-bash: grep-C3: command not found
kai@PC:~$ fixthis
grep -C3 error [enter/↑/↓/ctrl+c]
```

I only just installed it (in a moment of frustration with my job, frustration unrelated to the Unix CLI), so I don't know how good it is.

It does seem a bit slow so far, but it works.

Instructions here: https://ostechnix.com/correct-errors-in-linux-commands/

Summary for install (name of tool corrected to avoid profanity and offense, so replace the first 'x' below with a 'u'):

```
pip3 install --user thefxck
emacs ~/.bashrc  # add alias
source ~/.bashrc
grep-C3 error
fixthis
```